# fomulário dinâmico python django

Tags: django, python-2.7

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto que tem a necessidade de que um formulário seja criado mediante o tamanho da quantidade de item que for criado em um outro formulário.
O formulário inicial é o FormRota:

```
    class FormRota(forms.ModelForm):
        researcher =forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Profile.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}) )
   establishment=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Establishment.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
        product_to_search = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'checkbox-inline'}))
        date = forms.DateField(label='Data do registro', widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Data de entrada de dados'}))
```

Que o outro formulário o pesquisa:

```
class FormSeach(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Seach
        fields = ['rout', 'price_product']
```

o campo `price_product` precisa ser criado pelo tamanho do `product_to_search` que está no FormRota.

Alguém pode me ajudar, como faço para que sejam criados campos dinamicamente nos formulários? 
A versão que uso é a 1.3 do django!

Grato!

Comment: Está desenvolvendo do 0 ou é manutenção? Algum motivo em especial para usar o django 1.3?

Comment: É um projeto já existente, falta terminar!

Comment: Entendi. Veja se vale a pena atualizar a versão do django bem como as libs que utiliza. Se você tiver que dar manutenção no projeto, será trabalhoso com as coisas muito antigas.

Comment: Se você quer criar vários formulários a partir de um valor, da uma lida em inlineformset_factory e modelformset_factory para a versão do django que está utilizando. (Isso se entendi bem o seu caso)

Comment: O que preciso é que um campo seja replicado a quantidade de vezes que products_to_search tenha de produtos. Preciso que o campo rout fique estático e que seja repplicado os demais!

Comment: Carlos, conseguiu resolver este problema? Eu já implementei algo bem parecido. Se precisar só me avisa aqui e eu te ajudo melhor.

Comment: Olá  Antoniazzi, não consegui, na realidade eu até busquei outros caminhos e supriram a necessidade de tal momento, porém gostaria de sua ajuda a solucionar esta questão, é muito importante!